# Erro de Conexão C# PostGree - Locaweb

Tags: c#, postgresql

Prezados tenho um webservice consumindo dados postgreesql e quando tento conectar com a base após postar.
O host que estou tentando usar: "servidoripanema.no-ip.info"

> Npgsql.NpgsqlException: Failed to establish a connection 
>             to '177.195.43.242'. ---> 
>             System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the 
>             permission of type 'System.Net.SocketPermission,failed.

Entrei em contato com a locaweb e pra surpreza fizeram o teste porem em php e funcionou:

```
   <?php
    if(!@($conexao=pg_connect ("host=177.193.40.222 
     dbname=bdteste port=5438   user=admin password=xxxxx"))) {
     print "Não foi possível estabelecer uma conexão com o banco de dados.";
     } else {
     pg_close ($conexao);
     print "Conexão OK!"; 
     }
   ?>
```

Alguem ja passou por isso?

Comment: Cara, essa LocaWeb é jogar dinheiro fora (eu mesmo já usei)! Esse problema do TrustLevel é velho, [www.smarterasp.net](https://www.smarterasp.net/) é o melhor que conheço até agora! (Bem que eu poderia receber algum dinheiro pela propaganda, mas o serviço tem sido bom mesmo!)

Comment: O estranho é que quando mudo para o banco de dados oferecido por eles, funciona normalmente. Será que o Npgsql não permite conexoes por hostname?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa ter o TrustLevel da aplicação como `FullTrust` para executar o `NpgsqlException`.

A Locaweb não permite aplicações usando o `FullTrust`.

**Solução**: mude o *provider* ou a hospedagem.

Comment: O estranho é que quando mudo para o banco de dados oferecido por eles, funciona normalmente. Será que o Npgsql não permite conexoes por hostname?

Comment: @AndersonMachado como eu já disse, o problema é que a locaweb não te permite rodar aplicações como fulltrust. Isso não é um problema com o npgsql

Comment: è rapaz, acabei de crer. coloquei no windows azure e funcionou. Essa LocaWeb é um atraso de vida.